# vagrant install plugin from github

Tags: ruby, github, rubygems, vagrant

We are using Vagrant for deployment and we'd eventually like to deploy this cluster on Rackspace. The [vagrant-rackspace](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-rackspace) plugin is a natural choice, but it has a few bugs that are not included in the latest 0.1.1 release ([notably that `vagrant provision` doesn't work](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-rackspace/pull/16)). I've resolved this issue in my [personal fork](https://github.com/deanmalmgren/vagrant-rackspace) of the repository by merging work from others. Is it possible to do install a vagrant plugin from github?

The obvious thing didn't work:

```
[unix]$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-rackspace --plugin-source https://github.com/deanmalmgren/vagrant-rackspace
Installing the 'vagrant-rackspace' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
The plugin 'vagrant-rackspace' could not be found in local or remote
repositories. Please check the name of the plugin and try again.
```

I'm new to vagrant and ruby, so any pointers here would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As of today I see only two workarounds:

1. you could `rake build` the plugin, upload the resulting .gem to [gemfury](http://gemfury.com), and then use this as the `--plugin-source`.
2. you could install the plugin from a local source, e.g. `vagrant plugin install /path/to/your/bugfixed.gem`

In the end, I would love to see something like a `Gemfile` for Vagrant plugins. AFAIK there ain't no such thing yet but here is a [feature request](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1789)

**EDIT:** actually there is an awesome project called [bindler](https://github.com/fgrehm/bindler) now. The feature request to [add git location support in bindler](https://github.com/fgrehm/bindler/issues/4) is still outstanding, but this is the place where it should be fixed imho

Comment: It turns out you don't need to upload the .gem to gemfury, you can also just `vagrant plugin install pkg/pluginname-version` from within the plugin directory. More [here](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1829). Perhaps update answer?

Comment: @dino right you can do that, but it requires you to 1) git checkout + 2) rake build + 3) vagrant plugin install -- so it's a 3-step process still

Comment: Second option worked for me: vagrant plugin install install/vagrant-cloud9-0.5.0.dev.gem