# Add a local gem into a Vagrantfile

Tags: ruby, rubygems, vagrant, vagrantfile

Is there a "clean" way to add a local gem into a `Vagrantfile`?

I'm new to Ruby and Vagrant and I'm playing with Vagrant 1.6.5 and Ruby on a Mac OS X.

I'm trying to write a new gem, I want to add it into one or more `Vagrantfile`, placed in different directories. I would like to edit the gem and immediately see how it works every time I execute `vagrant`.

So I have edited the `Gemfile` adding the following line:

```
gem 'myvagrantgem', :path => "~/wsruby/myvagrantgem"
```

And I have added this line into a `Vagrantfile`:

```
require 'myvagrantgem'
```

But when I try to execute `vagrant`:

```
There was an error loading a Vagrantfile. The file being loaded
and the error message are shown below. This is usually caused by
a syntax error.

Path: /Users/freedev/wsruby/vagrant-ubuntu-lxc/Vagrantfile
Message: cannot load such file -- myvagrantgem
```

I could also specify the absolute path of my ruby file. 
But I suppose that, in Ruby, if I want to add a new object or a library I should specify a gem dependency.

Comment: Run `bundle` in project dir after every update of `Gemfile`.

Comment: I cannot run `bundle` because Vagrant runs into his own environment where gems are private. Please take a look at `/Applications/Vagrant/bin/vagrant`

Comment: Aye, I see, sorry for misleading answer. Might this link help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17028132/vagrant-install-plugin-from-github#17034820